# Angular CanActivated: canActivated return toPromise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to return a promise function in Angular `canActivate` function. How to convert the codes below so that it can return promise. I know I can use `toPromise()` to make it works but since `toPromise` is marked as deprecated. How to use `lastValueFrom()` so that it can produce the same result.

```js
canActivate(
    _route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    _state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | boolean
    | UrlTree {
    const token: string | null = this.cookieService.getCookie('webguard-token')
    const tokenValidated = token === null ? '' : token

    return this.webguardService
      .validateUserHasPermission('IsModerator')
      .toPromise()
      .then(async () => {
        return await this.webguardService
          .validateToken(tokenValidated)
          .toPromise()
          .then(() => {
            return true
          })
          .catch(() => {
            window.location.replace('/webguard/login/')
            return false
          })
      })
      .catch(() => {
        window.location.replace('/webguard/login/')
        return false
      })
  }
```

I tried to use `lastValueFrom()` but `canActivate()` is not an async function. I don't know how to use `lastValueFrom()` in `canActvate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lastValueFrom()` is a function that wraps an Observable:

```
return lastValueFrom(this.webguardService.validateUserHasPermission('IsModerator'))
  .then(async () => await 
    lastValueFrom(this.webguardService.validateToken(tokenValidated))
      .then(...)
```

Btw, you could do the same with just RxJS Observable and chain `mergeMap()`, `catchError()` and similar operators.